# jQM selectmenu with icon, move header left

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a jQM selectmenu with an icon and centered text. "Problem" is that it's beeing centered a few pixels off the center due to the icon. My icon is to the left, so I'd like to something like `padding-right: <width-of-icon> px;`

```
<select id="myselect" data-iconpos="left">
    <option value=""  disabled="disabled" selected="selected">I'm not really centered</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Zt8y5/)**

You just need to equalize the left and right padding on the DIV jQM creates when enhancing the select:

```
.ui-select .ui-btn-icon-left, .ui-select .ui-btn-icon-right {
    padding-left: 2.5em !important;
    padding-right: 2.5em !important;
}
```

This handles either right or left icon positioning.

Comment: Worked perfect! How did you know it's 2.5em?

Comment: If you use the web inspector to analyze the DOM, you will see that the jQM classes apply a 2.5em padding to allow for the icon.  You can also look directly in the jQM CSS file.